# creating custom field in jira

Tags: jira

I can't find a way to create this kind of custom field in Jira..

[image]

What is the custom field type for this kind of custom field?

I have tried with Label types, Select List(multiple choices)
type custom fields, but no result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at [their documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Labeling+an+Issue) and the applicable comments, it is indeed a Label field-type, as one would naturally assume.

The drop-down next to the labels is for the list of available or suggested labels.

Comment: @Nuwan - has this answered your question?

Comment: yes, but have a small question. I created the field like you said but the thing is how to set values for this field ...I only able add default values.how do I get this values as drop down list? reason is  with when I open the create issue page its already filled the newly created custom field with the values I added.

Answer (score 0):

this url may help you if you are using jira cloud

Link [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Custom-Label/qaq-p/1526270)

if you are using jira datacenter or jira server then

- you must have admin access
- go to the setting cog icon at the left side of screen .
- go to the issues then click **custom field in the left hand side**

add custom field
[Search label as in pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyfSu.png)